# Plain English explanation of Bernoulli mixture models?

Tags: conditional-probability, intuition, probability

Not exactly the most accessible explanation can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model), but I'm looking for something more intuitive, examples of applications and so on.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A typical example is a population of coins. There are biased coins which give Tails with probability 0.6, biased coins that give Tails with probability 0.4, and fair coins (probability 0.5). If you know how many coins there are circulating of each type, you can construct a mixture. Given an unknown coin, the distribution over possible probabilities is then given by this mixture.

Comment: "Distribution over possible probabilities" could benefit from clarification: probabilities of *what*?  The type of coin that is drawn?  The chance that it will come up heads?  The chances in a sequence of trials involving this coin?  The chances in a sequence of trials where each time a new coin is chosen?  Also, is anything special meant by a "possible" probability as opposed to just a probability?